# Is it possible to add pixels to an 'auto' value?

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to animate an image that has `position: absolute;` adding some pixels to its default value. As it is default, the `left` property is `auto`.

The problem it is that the pixels that I am trying to add, are not added to the actual position of the image, it seems that they are been added to the left of the browser window, regardless of the position of the image.

This is my `HTML` code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

        <script type="text/javascript">

           function moveImage(){
                $("#image").animate({
                    left: "+=300px"
                }, 1000);  
           }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button type="button" onclick="moveImage()">Move image</button>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="left" class="block">Left</div>
            <div id="center" class="block">
                <img id="image" src="https://appharbor.com/assets/images/stackoverflow-logo.png" alt="stackoverflow">
            </div>
            <div id="right" class="block">Right</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my `CSS` code:

```
html, body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#container{
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
}

.block{
    flex: 1;
}

#left{
    background-color: red;
}

#center{
    background-color: yellow;
}

#right{
    background-color: orange;
}

#image{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

**Note:** I simplified my code as much I could because it was very extended but it is the same behaviour that I am having on my project.

**Note 2:** As I simplified the code, in my project I pass the value of `left: "+=300px"` with a variable, but I put 300px so you can see the behaviour that I am getting.

**Note 3:** I am using `jquery-2.2.3.min.js` and `Google Chrome` on my project but here I put the online link for Jquery and in both cases I get the same behaviour.

**Note 4**: If you put in the console `$("#image").css('left');` it retrieves to you the value `'auto'`.

***My question***

Is it possible that the pixels that I am adding to that 'auto' value would be added to the actual position of the image and not on the left of the browser window?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `position: absolute` it is its first parent with a non static positioning that will be the reference to the left/top position and since no one has that, it will be the body.

Add `position: relative;` to your `#center` rule and it will work as expected.

```css
html, body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#container{
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
}

.block{
    flex: 1;
}

#left{
    background-color: red;
}

#center{
    position: relative;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#right{
    background-color: orange;
}

#image{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  function moveImage(){
    $("#image").animate({
      left: "+=300px"
    }, 1000);  
  }
</script>

<button type="button" onclick="moveImage()">Move image</button>
<div id="container">
  <div id="left" class="block">Left</div>
  <div id="center" class="block">
    <img id="image" src="https://appharbor.com/assets/images/stackoverflow-logo.png" alt="stackoverflow">
  </div>
  <div id="right" class="block">Right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you! I though its parent would be the flex object but I forgot that when you set `position: absolute` to an element it search for its nearer parent that has `position: absolute` or `position: relative`. Thank you again!

Comment: If there is no positioned ancestor, the absolutely positioned element is bound to the *initial containing block*, not the `body` element (unless, of course, `body` is a positioned element). For all practical purposes, the initial containing block is the root element / viewport. https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#comp-abspos

Comment: @Michael_B In this case, and with no positioned ancestor, it would be the html element being the root element, correct?

Comment: Yes, I believe that's correct. If there are no positioned ancestors, the containing block is the initial containing block, which is the viewport, which is, at least in this case, the root element.